# Imagick::getImageFormat returns "PNG" for svg

Tags: php, svg, imagemagick, imagick

I'm using imagick to check the format of an image in PHP like this:

```
$image = new Imagick('simple.svg');
echo $image->getImageFormat();
```

To my suprise, the output is `PNG`, even though `Imagick::queryFormats()` lists `SVG` as a known type.
Everything from apache, to PHP, to imagick should be up to date (fresh install):

```
PHP Version                                 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3
----------------------------------------------------------------------
imagick module version                      3.4.0RC6
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version   ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-03-14
Imagick using ImageMagick library version   ImageMagick 6.8.9-9 Q16 x86_64 2016-11-29
ImageMagick release date                    2016-11-29
```

I've tried different .svg files, all returning `PNG`. One of the simple svg files I tried is from Wikipedia [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/85/Cyclohexane_simple.svg). Any ideas why imagick returns a false format? Rastered graphics like jpg and png are detected correctly.

EDIT:

Using `Imagick::pingImage` before `Imagick::identifyImage` returns PNG as well:

```
[mimetype] => image/png 
[format] => PNG (Portable Network Graphics) 
[units] => Undefined 
[type] => Bilevel 
[colorSpace] => Gray
[compression] => Undefined 
[fileSize] => 7.05KB 
[geometry] => Array ( [width] => 320 [height] => 372 )
[resolution] => Array ( [x] => 72 [y] => 72 )
```

The .svg file is definitely not a PNG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="480" height="543.03003" viewBox="0 0 257.002 297.5" xml:space="preserve">
<g transform="matrix(0.8526811,0,0,0.8526811,18.930632,21.913299)">
<polygon points="8.003,218.496 0,222.998 0,74.497 8.003,78.999 8.003,218.496 "/>
<polygon points="128.501,287.998 128.501,297.5 0,222.998 8.003,218.496 128.501,287.998 " />
<polygon points="249.004,218.496 257.002,222.998 128.501,297.5 128.501,287.998 249.004,218.496 " />
<polygon points="249.004,78.999 257.002,74.497 257.002,222.998 249.004,218.496 249.004,78.999 " />
<polygon points="128.501,9.497 128.501,0 257.002,74.497 249.004,78.999 128.501,9.497 " />
<polygon points="8.003,78.999 0,74.497 128.501,0 128.501,9.497 8.003,78.999 " />
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Imagemagick works with raster images; I wonder if the svg is converted when read? You can ping an image with Imagick::pingImage I wonder what that will return.

Comment: I tried ping and `identifyImage`, the results are in my original post.

Comment: Using current ImageMagick-7.0.4-1, `magick identify *.svg` returns
file.svg SVG 480x543 480x543+0+0 16-bit sRGB 813B 0.000u 0:00.079

Comment: @user7367183 Feel free to open a bug at https://github.com/mkoppanen/imagick/issues - I'll look at it....this year.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems solved on ImageMagick 7+
But I ran into a similar problem identifying a PDF on Ubuntu 16 with ImageMagick 7.0.6-0. It kept returning PNG for some unknown reason.

I have no definite fix, but there is a way to work around such issues by overloading Imagick.

```
<?php
class MyImagick extends Imagick{
    private function getimageidentifiction() {
        $filename       = parent::getimagefilename();
        return exec('identify -format "%m\n" -quiet "' . addslashes($filename) .'"| head -n 1');
    }

    public function getimageformat() {
        return $this->getimageidentifiction();
    }
}
```

You can then use `$possible_image   = new MyImagick($filename);` to load the image/pdf.
And `$possible_image->getimageformat();` to get the imageformat => which will be PDF.

Comment: Not only Imagick7 is affected, I've got the same problem on ImageMagick 6.8.9-9